# Why do two pointer pointing to the same link behave differently here?

Tags: c++, list

```
void fillList(ListNode *&emp,int a[],int n){
    ListNode *e=new ListNode(a[0]);
    emp=e;
    for(int i=1;i<n;++i){
        e=e->next;
        e=new ListNode(a[i]);
    }
}
void showList(ListNode *l){
    while(l){
        cout<<l->val<<' ';
        l=l->next;
    }
}
```

I wrote two functions here, one to fill a empty link with an array, the other to output the link. But when I output the link, it's only the first element from the array. What have I done wrong?
  The program is listed as follows. Thanks so much.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
  };
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        ListNode *p1=l1, *p2=l2, *n1, *n2;
        while(p1&&p2){
            p1=p1->next;
            p2=p2->next;
        }
        if(p2){n1=l2;n2=l1;}else{n1=l1;n2=l2;}
        bool b=0;
        while(l1){
            if((l1->val+=l2->val)>=10){l1->val-=10;b=1;}
            l1=l1->next;
            l2=l2->next;
            if(b)if(l1)l1->val++;else l1=new ListNode(1);
        }
        return n1;
    }
};
void fillList(ListNode *&emp,int a[],int n){
    ListNode *e=new ListNode(a[0]);
    emp=e;
    for(int i=1;i<n;++i){
        e=e->next;
        e=new ListNode(a[i]);
    }
}
void showList(ListNode *l){
    while(l){
        cout<<l->val<<' ';
        l=l->next;
    }
}
 int main(){
    Solution sol;
    ListNode *l1=0,*l2=0;
    int a[]={2,4,3},b[]={5,6,4};
    fillList(l1,a,3);
    fillList(l2,b,3);
    //cout<<l1->val<<endl;
    showList(l1);
    showList(l2);
    showList(sol.addTwoNumbers(l1,l2));
 }
```

Comment: And when you stepped through your program with a debugger, one line at a time, what observations did you make? The obvious bug in this code should be trivially observable, in your debugger.

Comment: I saw that I can't cout emp->next->val because emp->next is null. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I really want to thank you for your **question**, very complete.

Actually the problem lies here

```
for(int i=1;i<n;++i){
    e=e->next;
    e=new ListNode(a[i]);
}
```

you should change it to the following code to **connect** all the newly created nodes

```
for(int i=1;i<n;++i){
    e->next = new ListNode(a[i]);
    e=e->next;
}
```